# Importing csv file as an api query

Tags: r, dataframe, api, csv, get

So I am trying to call a "Content-Type: text/csv" API and then convert it into a readable format in r.

The call was successful, however managing the returned object is the current challenge.

Although, I have seen examples with just JSON Object, and I believe managing this content-type should be easier to handle but this is my first direct API call.

Here is what I have tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rjson)
library(jsonlite)
library(RCurl)
library(httr)

## Export Data URL
url = 'http://api.abc.com/api/users'

headers = c('accept' = {'application/json'},
            'Accept-Language' = {'hi_IN'},
            'User-Agent' = {'Mozilla/4.0'})

## Raw Data
api_raw <- GET(url, add_headers(headers))
```

```
api_raw
```

As Shah as pointed out, I have been able to isolate the text response, however the challenge now is in converting this *data* into a readable form.

I have tried the following:

```
setwd("~/Automated Reports/R/BME-Export")
data <- httr::content(api_raw, as = 'text')

data_2 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data)
```

Here I get this error

> Error: parse error: unallowed token at this point in JSON text
> ,Lat,Long,Popu
> (right here) ------^
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: package ‘RCurl’ was built under R version 4.1.1
> 2: package ‘httr’ was built under R version 4.1.1

```
## Read the data as csv
df_api <- read.csv(data)
```

Here I get the following error

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In file(file, "rt") :
> cannot open file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `httr::content` function.

```
data <- httr::content(api_raw, 'text')
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this.

Please it seem to be an atomic vector, how do I convert this into a tidy data frame.

I have tried ```df <- as.data.frame(data)``` but this does not work.

Comment: I have run into a challenge of converting the *data* into a useable form. Whenever I run ```df <- read.csv(data)``` it returns this error : * Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file ',Lat,Long, ....*

Comment: Finally figured it out
```read.csv(text = data) # It was important that the data was called as text.```

Thanks Shan

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could get:

`data <- httr::GET(url) %>% httr::content("parsed")`